# Temporary directory in node not working randomly. Works sometimes but not others

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, google-cloud-functions, fs

I am using GCP functions in a Firebase web app. I am having trouble accessing the tmp directory properly. What I am doing incorrectly?
(The odd thing is that the code seems to also work randomly.)

```
const tmp = os.tmpdir();
const PdfPrinter = require('pdfmake');
const fs = require('fs');

const tmp = os.tmpdir()
const dd = [] 
const pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(dd);
pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${tmp}/relative.pdf`));
pdfDoc.end();

const attachment = fs.readFileSync(`${tmp}/relative.pdf`).toString("base64"); // error here
```

Error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/relative.pdf'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
    at /workspace/index.js:494:27
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Comment: Are you sure taht the pdfDoc functions are sync? If it's async, it's normal that it doesn't work: you read the file before its creation. If not, I don't know!

Comment: Please edit the question to show the complete, minimal code that you deploy, and include instructions on how to trigger it and observe the results.  What you have right now seems incomplete for the purpose of building a reproduction.  I suggest reading up on how to create a [complete minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  I also suggest updating the title to be more descriptive of the problem you're running into.

Comment: Any progress made?

Comment: @Sunkas, Yes, I will post the answer I ended up going with.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer I ended up going with. I had two attachments which I needed to wait until they were complete.

I ended up switching to using Buffer, but I think I could have used the `tmp` directory and it would have worked. Essentially, the function was just closing down before it was finished running. So, I set up some checks to make sure everything was finished.

```
    const docDefinition = {
        // normal doc definition
    }
    const pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
    const pdfTitle = workOrder.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, '')

    pdfDoc.on('data', (chunk) => {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    });
    let attachment
    pdfDoc.on('end', () => {
      const result = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      attachment = {
        content: result.toString('base64'),
        filename: `Estimate-${pdfTitle}.pdf`,
        type: "application/pdf",
        disposition: "attachment"
      }
    });

    pdfDoc.on('error', (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

    pdfDoc.end();

    const printer_2 = new Printer(fontDescriptors);
    const chunks_2 = [];
    const docDefinition_2 = {
        // normal doc definition
    }
    const pdfDoc_2 = printer_2.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition_2);

    pdfDoc_2.on('data', (chunk) => {
      chunks_2.push(chunk);
    });

    let attachment_2
    pdfDoc_2.on('end', () => {
      const result_2 = Buffer.concat(chunks_2)
      attachment_2 = {
        content: result_2.toString('base64'),
        filename: `Lumber-order-${pdfTitle}.pdf`,
        type: "application/pdf",
        disposition: "attachment"
      }
    });

    pdfDoc_2.on('error', (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
    pdfDoc_2.end();
    functions.logger.log('Log Before Interval Start')
```

This chunk of code makes sure that the function doesn't terminate before the two attachments are ready.

```
    async function waitUntil() {
      return await new Promise(resolve => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
          if (attachment && attachment_2) {
            clearInterval(interval)
            functions.logger.log('Attachments Ready')
            let attachments = []
            attachments.push(attachment)
            attachments.push(attachment_2)

            const msg = {
              // to, from, etc.. here
              attachments: attachments
            };
            resolve(msg)
          }
        }, 1000)
      })
    }

    const msg = await waitUntil()
    const resp = await sgMail.send(msg)
```

Comment: Sure. Looking at your solution this seems like a reliable solution. However, I'm still confused why storing a file does does not store immediately and the following code sometimes is sometimes run before the file is created. Your solution is better than mine, but still feels like a workaround.

Comment: I think it starts to store immediately, but it takes some time to finish storing. In my instance, it takes some time to finish creating the files.

Comment: But should not the save be async then? So we can wait for the file to be created. In my case I use excel4node which has an async creating function. But I still see the same issue as you do.

Comment: I think the answer to that is yes, it seems like it should.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue. I created a xlsx file with the framework `excel4node` and then I wanted to read it, to mail it as an attachment. I got the same error as you trying to read the file.  Mine also worked randomly.

I could not find a reasonable solution, but adding a small delay before reading the file seems to solve it.

```
// Function that creates the file and stores it in the /tmp-folder
await createExcelFile() 

// This solved it for me, add a small delay
await new Promise(f => setTimeout(f, 1000));

// Read the file again from tmp-folder
const pathToAttachment = "/tmp/" + reportFileName;
const attachment = fs.readFileSync(pathToAttachment).toString("base64");
```

Comment: I posted the code I used, which works all the time. I would just add something to your code to check that the attachment is actually ready. If it takes longer than 1 second to create the file, you may run into the same problem for those files.